# how to run different .js file in one server.js file in NODE JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

this is demo.js file and i want to use this file in server.js file so that i can use diffrent js files in one server file.

***Demo.js:***

```
    app.get('/add User', function (req, res) {
    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/project';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
             var collection = db.collection('users');
            collection.find({name: 'shruti'}).toArray(function (err, result) {
                console.log(, result);
                    db.close();
        });
```

***Server.js:***

```
    var a = require('./demo.js');
    vr http=require("http");

    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
      response.write(a);
      res.end();});
    server.listen(7860);
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @shruti-dengre To make something exportable, use `module.exports` in your Demo.js , but you also need a promise for whatever you're trying to accomplish here, since there is no guarantee that `a` will be populated before the `write` function gets fired. Read Javascript Promises or change your workflow.

Comment: if possible, add complete demo.js and app.js

Answer (score 1):

A possible sample would look like :

**demo.js**

```
var myModule = {
  defineRoutes: function(router){
    //do something...
  }
}

module.exports = myModule;
```

**server.js**

```
var myModule = require('demo.js');
myModule.defineRoutes(router);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you need to export. 
When you do:

```
var item = require("mymodule");
```

Require returns an object, which is a reference the value of module.exports for that given file  - in your case *demo.js.*

You can write your modules a few ways as some people have shown you. Because it is encapsulated you basically are identifying what is public or can be called. Few ways to write it - you could also do:

```
module.exports = {
  yourCall: function () {
     console.log("stuff here");
  }
};
```

As stated by @ishann, who is dead on here, you are writing something you assume might be populated. Going to a database and returning is an asynchronous call - so it will take time to go do that and then for the results to be returned.

Based on your structure - ideally what you want to do is assign the route ( "/addUser" ) which will pass in the response object to you:

```
app.get('/add User', function (req, res) {
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/project';
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
         var collection = db.collection('users');
        collection.find({name: 'shruti'}).toArray(function (err, result) {
            console.log(, result);
                db.close(); 
                 // set the type
                 res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                 res.write(result);

    });
```

Just looks like your code needs a bit of reorg, but separting concerns is good. You might want to also check out [Express as a framework](http://expressjs.com/) for node.